# How to get selected record in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For e.g.

```
<select class="form-control" id="group_id" name="group_id" 
ng-model="form.group_id" ng-options="match_group.id as match_group.name for match_group in match_groups"  
required="" ng-change="getGroupWiseMatches()">
....some code
</select>
```

But match_group instance will have id, name and xyz columns.

Now on the select of match_group, I also want value of xyz column.

How can we get it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: make it `ng-model="form.selectedMatch" ng-options=match_group as match_group.name for match_group in match_groups` so that `form.selectedMatch` has the entire selected object

Comment: Not like this. In dropdown I don't want to touch anything. id as option value and name as option text. It should be as is. But on select of it. I need that entry in js. so that I will use it somewhere else. `{ "id": 1, "name": "Test A", "xyz": "Some other value" }` I need this. but not as select element's value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the work around for this,

My html will be as it is,

```
<select class="form-control" id="group_id" name="group_id" 
ng-model="form.group_id" ng-options="match_group.id as match_group.name for match_group in match_groups"  
required="" ng-change="getGroupWiseMatches()">
....some code
</select>
```

And in js I am fetching selected entry as,

```
var found_record = $scope.match_groups.find(obj => obj.id === selected_id);
$scope.form.xyz = found_record.xyz;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ng-options` expression has the following format: "*select* as *label* for *value* in *array*".

The *select*-part is the result that is bound to your `ng-model`. So if you change your code to the following:

```
<select class="form-control" id="group_id" name="group_id" 
    ng-model="form.group" 
    ng-options="match_group as match_group.name for match_group in match_groups"  
    required="" ng-change="getGroupWiseMatches()">
    ....some code
</select>
```

your variable `form.group` would contain the entire group object, instead of just the id.

[Check this plunker to see it in action](https://plnkr.co/edit/n0E61hVccHdnP0JyTvNg?p=preview)

Comment: Not like this. In dropdown I don't want to touch anything. id as option value and name as option text. It should be as is. But on select of it. I need that entry in js. so that I will use it somewhere else. `{ "id": 1, "name": "Test A", "xyz": "Some other value" }`

Comment: You can simply access `$scope.form.group` in your controller. If this is not what the question is about, then please fix your question to be more clear about what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks mate! Anyway I found workaround for the same.